# How to show Alert like true caller even if app is close?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an SOS application.

When a notification is received in the Android app I want to open an alert pop-up, which will show some details of sender and SOS icons and also continuous alert tone will ring.

I was doing this by using the below code, but on android 9 Activity doesn't start. And this code doesn't start the activity when the app is in the killed state also not working on background mode.

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody, String notificationType, String notificationId) {       

    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SosPopUpActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("message", messageBody);
        intent.putExtra("notification_type", notificationType);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    channelId, channelName, importance);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }


        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        //  NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setSound(Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sos))

                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
            notificationBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            //notificationBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notification_color));
        } else {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
        }

        notificationBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

        //  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // notificationManager.notify(1234, notificationBuilder.build());

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(1234, notificationBuilder.build());

        startActivity(intent);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        AlertDialogHelper.showAlertDialog(this,e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: there is no crash log activity doesn't start

Comment: Then what do you mean through "And this code doesn't start the activity when the app is killed."?

Comment: When app is killed , not in foreground , also in bacground mode it is not working . @AlexMamo